# jboss netty channel buffers thread safety

Tags: jboss, netty

I'm writing small utility app (JBoss Netty based) which should perform some trivial login against http requests.

Imagine an image buffer

```
private static byte[] image = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("...some base64 data here....");

private static final ChannelBuffer imageBuf = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(image);
```

So, the question is: Is it correct to share this `imageBuf` across multiple threads for writing? Or should I create the new one for each response?

Comment: And it is no longer JBoss Netty I think. Netty moved to a new home netty.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope its not safe to share the ChannelBuffer accross Threads. ChannelBuffer's are not thread-safe